# Is there a way to join lines after a match expression in awk?

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to format in a better way a text. I want to join conditionally two subsequent line in awk: if the line end in "." print the line as it is, if the line doesn't end in "." join this and the subsequent line if the latter begin in lowercase.

i have tried this calling awk -f scriptfile textfile

```
{ if ( $NF ~ /.*\./ )
    print $0;
  else {
    line_p=$0;
    getline;
    if ( $0 ~ /^[ a-z]+/ )
        print line_p, $0;
    else {
        print line_p;
        print $0
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried on this:

```
io sono un segno
cavallo come un cammello.
Il mio vitello si chiama segno di
Budd chiari. Se non fosse così:
-cavalli eterni 
-eterni cavalli
opere incompiute
```

but the output is this:

```
io sono un segno cavallo come un cammello.
Il mio vitello si chiama segno di
Budd chiari. Se non fosse così:
-cavalli eterni 
-eterni cavalli
opere incompiute opere incompiute
```

i don't understand the last repetition and why line 6 and 7 are not joined together

expected:

```
io sono un segno cavallo come un cammello.
Il mio vitello si chiama segno di
Budd chiari. Se non fosse così:
-cavalli eterni 
-eterni cavalli opere incompiute
```

Comment: i've edited the question

Comment: What happens if the latter line doesn't start with lower case but the previous line didn't end with a `.`. For instance your `-eterni cavalli` line doesn't start with a lowercase and yet it's joined up to the previous line. This appears to violate your rule. How come `opere incompiute` doesn't get joined to the previous line which doesn't end with a `.`?  Your expected output doesn't seem to follow your rules.

Comment: sorry i've edited again the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^[[:lower:]]/ && (p !~ /\.$/) ? ofs : ors), $0; ofs=OFS; ors=ORS} {p=$0} END{print ""}' file
io sono un segno cavallo come un cammello.
Il mio vitello si chiama segno di
Budd chiari. Se non fosse così:
-cavalli eterni
-eterni cavalli opere incompiute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the output record separator to an empty string and set a flag based on whether the current line ends with a `.`, so that when you processing the next line you can manually output either a space or a newline based on the flag and whether the current line starts with a lowercase letter before printing the current line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""}{if(/\.$/){print" ";a=2}else{if(a==2||/^[^a-z]/){print "\n"}else{if(a)print" "};a=1}}END{print"\n"}1' textfile
```

This outputs:

```
io sono un segno cavallo come un cammello.
Il mio vitello si chiama segno di
Budd chiari. Se non fosse così:
-cavalli eterni 
-eterni cavalli opere incompiute
```